# Got request :request body parameter is empty

Tags: node.js

I am using 'node-oauth2-server' module to generate Oauth2.0 token, but I am getting below error when trying to generate token using request :

Error :

```
   400, {
       code: 400,
       message: 'Invalid or missing grant_type parameter',
       name: 'invalid_request'
 }
```

Request details :

```
  const apiResponse= httpRequest('http://localhost:3000/auth/refresh-token-for-product',
    {

        form:{
            username: data.userId+"/"+data.id,
            password: data.password,
            grant_type: "password",
            client_id: 'null',
            client_secret: 'null'
        },
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            //'Authorization': data.header
        }
    })
```

**Note** : It is working fine on  localhost, the issue is on serve only. I am doing request on same server to grant token hence url like localhost is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to confusing docs of **got** module , I am getting req.body to empty. I called got request with body and form option like below and it is working now.

```
const apiResponse= httpRequest('http://localhost:3000/auth/refresh-token-for-product',
    {
        form : true, //here is the change 
        body : {   //here is the change 
            username: data.userId+"/"+data.id,
            password: data.password,
            grant_type: "password",
            client_id: 'null',
            client_secret: 'null'
        },
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            //'Authorization': data.header
        }
    })
```